# Why is this not in the Dockerfile?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I've been messing with Docker and Django lately and rather than clutter up my system, I decided to make a dev container for Django.
I've got it working but I want to know the "why" of this situation.

I followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) tutorial on the Docker website and finally got everything working. I don't get ***why*** we do
`docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample`  and not put the `django-admin startproject composeexample`  inside the Dockerfile or the compose file?

EDIT: Here's what I have tried with my limited Docker knowledge:
On separate Dockerfiles I've tried...
`CMD django-admin startproject django-tests` and `CMD ['django-admin startproject django-tests']`
And I tried...
`command: django-admin startproject django-tests`

I've tried to do both but it wont work, it builds the image but without a django project being created. I get a `manage.py not found` error.
I feel like the project should be inside the image and not have to be run at the end of the `docker-compose run` command.

So why do we do this and why doesn't putting it inside the Dockerfile work?

Comment: It would help if you would show us what "I've tried to do both but it won't work" looks like.

Comment: Edited main post with the commands I tried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't get why we do docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample and not put the django-admin startproject composeexample inside the Dockerfile or the compose file?

Because this command is a one-time initialization command that creates a Django project template *in your current directory* on the host. It doesn't make sense to bake this into a Dockerfile; you will only ever run this once when first creating your project. That's why you're using `docker-compose run` here, which is for short-lived ad-hoc commands.

Compare the directory before `docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .`:

```
$ ls
docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile  requirements.txt
```

And after:

```
$ ls
composeexample  docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile  manage.py  requirements.txt
```

Running that command created the `composeexample` directory tree and `manage.py` files for us.

This works because of the `volume` configuration in the
`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

That mounts the current directory (`.`) as `/code` inside the
container. Meanwhile, the `Dockerfile` makes `/code` the current
working directory:

```
WORKDIR /code
```

So when we run the `startproject` command, files are created inside
`/code` inside the container which corresponds to our local directory
on the host.

Comment: I was under the impression that an image is built once and then a container is created from that image. So, in my mind, creating it inside the image made sense but now I see why that wouldn't be useful. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You're correct that an image is built once and then a container is created from the image. That's largely why we in this example we create the django project at runtime, rather than baking the command into the image, because it allows us to use the same image for multiple projects without needing to rebuild it every time.

Answer (score -1):

`I don't get why we do docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample  and not put the django-admin startproject composeexample  inside the Dockerfile or the compose file?`

Because you don't want to create a new project inside a container. We want to build it locally, add it to container and have the container ready to go with all necessary files wherever this container is deployed.

`manage.py not found`

This means that you either have not copied the project files into your container or you run you command inside the wrong directory. You can do `WORKDIR` in the docker-compose or you can get inside your container (it must be running) with

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
```

and see which folder your project is in (if it's there)

Comment: It all works fine when I build locally and do exactly what you said. The reason it's missing the file is because the django project wasn't being built and that is what was confusing me. Why not build inside the image and then remote connect to the container to develop?

Comment: Building the project every time you deploy a container defeats the purpose of containers. Containers have all the settings and ensure that your code works inside the container and all the files for your project to work are in there. Containers eliminate the need to setup the environment for deployment. You need to get into your docker-compose because the problem is probably there, you might not copy the right stuff or you are running your commands in the wrong folder.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There isn't a "problem" as the code works, it was more of a theoretical question of WHY this thing s done in this manner instead of another. You and larsks both put me on the right track so, thank you for the comments! :)